# Deleting oldest files from a subdirectory in a directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have an archive folder, inside which some sub folders (as A,B,C) containing archived files.How to find and delete the oldest created files from sub folders (say B)which I want?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are trying to delete the oldest modified file (not created), then you can use this:

```
rm "$(ls -t | tail -1)"
```

Comment: OP did say _oldest created fileS_ and that fails with for example: `ls "$(ls -t | tail -2)"`.

Answer (score 1):

This command would do exactly what you desired,

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | awk 'NR==1{print $2}' | xargs rm -v
```

Brief explanation,

- `find . -mindepth 2 -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n'`: limit the min depth to 2, it means `find` would only show the files under the sub-directories or even further. And then prints the file's last modification time and its name.
- Pipe the output of `find ...` to `sort` to sort the modification time of all found files.
- `awk 'NR==1{print $2}'`: pipe the output to `awk` to get the name of oldest file
- `xargs rm -v`: remove the oldest file

**Eidt**

For further request to pass the sub-directories name using variables, here's the modified method to use. You only need to modify the `awk` part,

```
$ a="sub_dir1"
$ b="sub_dir2"
$ find ... | sort | awk -v a=$a -v b=$b '$2 ~ "./" a "/" || $2 ~ "./" b "/"{print $2 ;exit}' | xargs ...
```

Comment: Agree.I will be calling the function which include this command from another script. Here I want to pass the sub folder name (as A/B/C) from that script. How to call the function in another script from this script with parameter as sub folder name?

Comment: @Anony, see my modification for your further request.

Comment: Works fine..Thanks..Issue is when there are no files to delete inside B, need to move to A/C according to disk usage of them. How?I want do do this from the delete_function only

Comment: According to your post, you request to delete the oldest file under the desired sub-directories. So what you mean no files to be deleted inside B, in that way, the command would delete oldest one in A/C. What you mean "move to A/C according to disk usage of them"??

Comment: I am considering the total size of archive folder and need the size to be reduced to half. So I need to delete files from sub folders. Here in B folder no files and size of archive didn't reduce to half, I should move to other one and delete files from there.

Comment: OK, if no files under B, the command would not find the oldest one under B, but go to remove the oldest one under A/C.

Comment: And I don't think @rmdcoding's answer would fix it. Why do you check it as acceptance?

Comment: Modified date is also fine for me. Please explain how it will go and check other folders too

Comment: Did you try the command? If there's no files under B, it will go to A to show the oldest file as implied in the `awk` command `$2 ~ "./" a "/" || $2 ~ "./" b "/"`. If you also need search under another sub-directory named C, follow the logic to add it to the `awk` command would be fine.