# How to remove all directories except for the last one

Tags: bash

I can get the amount of dirs with command

```
ls -dtr */ | wc -l
```

But how do I specifically delete the N-1 directories, leaving the most recent one?

Comment: Note that this question might be better answered on the [Unix&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46461468/deleting-oldest-files-from-a-subdirectory-in-a-directory) and [another on Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242496/bash-script-to-remove-the-oldest-file-from-from-a-folder). However, I would avoid the accepted answers as they rely on parsing `ls`'s output, which is prone to failure.

Comment: Actually `ls -dtr */ | wc -l` may not produce the number of subdirectories in the current directory.  Things that can break it include: subdirectories with names beginning with `-`, symlinks to directories, an absence of subdirectories, and subdirectories whose names contain the newline character.

Answer (score 4):

As usual for any bash operation on "a bunch of files", you have to be aware of the pain that is spaces and newlines, which may legally appear in file names. These break naïve `xargs` / `for` based approaches and require some extra hoops to jump.

Many tools support `-z` or `-0` options, which use NUL bytes as line separator instead of newlines -- NUL may never be part of a file name.

Unfortunately, `ls` is not one of them, so we have to go through `find` to get the latest directory.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d
```

This gets you all the directories in the current directory. (Note: As opposed to your `ls -dtr */`, this will *also* find "hidden" directories, i.e. ones starting with a `.`. Add `! -name ".*"` to avoid that.)

`-maxdepth 1` avoids recursion, `-mindepth 1` keeps the parent directory (`.`) out of the list.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf "%T+ %f\0"
```

This lists the directories and their timestamps, using NUL instead of newline for line separation. (NUL can never be part of a file name.)

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf "%T+ %f\0" | sort -z
```

This sorts the results, using NUL instead of newline for line separation.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf "%T+ %f\0" | sort -z | head -z -n -1
```

This takes everything but the last entry (the latest directory and its timestamp) from the list, using NUL instead of newline for line separation.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf "%T+ %f\0" | sort -z | head -z -n -1 | cut -z -d' ' -f 2-
```

Using NUL instead of newline for line separation and space as field delimiter, this filters the first field (the timestamp) from the output.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf "%T+ %f\0" | sort -z | head -z -n -1 | cut -z -d' ' -f 2- | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Using NUL instead of newline for line separation, this calls `rm -rf` for each entry.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tail`:

```
ls -dt */ | tail -n +2 | while read dirName; do rmdir "$dirName"; done
```

When specifying the `-n` option of `tail` with a `+`, it skips the first lines.

This will list the directories sorted by date, skip the most recent one and keep the rest, which will be deleted. You can replace `rmdir` with `rm -rf` following your use case.

You can try it out:

```
mkdir test && cd test
for i in {1..100}; do mkdir subdir-$i; done
ls -dt */ | tail -n +2 | while read dirName; do rmdir "$dirName"; done
ls
```

Output:

```
subdir-100
```

**EDIT**: if any of the directory names contain newline characters, this approach will fail because of `tail`. See @DevSolar's answer for a more complete one in that case.

Comment: This fails when any directory name includes a space character(s).

Comment: thanks - Another way is: `ls -dt */ | tail -n +2 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm -rf`. Here we pipe the output from `tail` to `tr` replacing newlines with a NUL character. Then utilize the `-0` option with `xargs`  to expect NUL characters as separators, instead of spaces and newlines.

Comment: @RobC: If you have newlines in the file names, the output is already broken by the `tail` part.

Comment: @DevSolar -  yes you're correct. I was about to post a more comprehensive answer covering that. Then I read yours `+1` - I actually find newline chars in names difficult to test for - I use mac and newlines aren't permitted to my understanding.

Comment: Yes, the `tail` trick won't be enough if there are newline characters in the filenames. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @RobC: `touch $'foo\nbar'` should do. (Some shell commands, like a "naked" `ls`, will output the newline as `?`, but it is there -- check with `for file in $(ls *); do echo "-$file-"; done`.) (Not tested on Mac as I don't have one, that's just how you'd do it on Unix.)

Comment: The issues with using the output of `ls` are described in [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  This attempted solution also fails if any of the directories has a name that begins with `-` (although that is easy to fix).  In addition, it may fail if the directory contains symlinks to directories. Finally (for problems that I can think of right now) it will produce an error message if it is run in a directory that contains no subdirectories.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pure Bash solution:

```
shopt -s nullglob   # Globs that match nothing expand to nothing
shopt -s dotglob    # Globs include files whose names start with '.'

newest_dir=
for sdir in */ ; do
    dir=${sdir%/}               # Remove slash to enable a symlink check
    [[ -L $dir ]] && continue   # Skip symlinks to directories

    if [[ -z $newest_dir ]] ; then
        newest_dir=$dir
    elif [[ $dir -nt $newest_dir ]] ; then
        echo rm -rf  -- "$newest_dir"
        newest_dir=$dir
    else
        echo rm -rf -- "$dir"
    fi
done
```

In its current form it just prints the commands to remove the old subdirectories.  Remove the `echo`s to make it functional.

Answer (score 0):

So many ways, here's another. :)

```
rm -rf `ls -1dt * | tail -n +2 | tr '\n' ' '`
```

First, the `ls -1dt *` just lists all the directories sorted by modification time, one per line.  Then `tail -n +2` removes the first, most recently modified.  Then `tr '\n ' '` puts them all into a single line.  Then the `rm -rf` the dirs.

Comment: This uses `ls` so it also fails if the filename contains newline character(s) - as mentioned [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).